# ASP .NET MVC - files access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, routes

I'm trying to configure routing in my application in such way: paths to files should work for every directory except one special. And access to files in this direcotory should be processed by my controller action. If I write smth like this:

```
routes.Map("Specialfolder/{name}", "Controller", "Action");
```

it works only for unexisting files. Controller doesn't catches route for existing file

If I add this line:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Working with files in my folder is ok. But files in other directories aren't routed anymore. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try using the file extension as part of the route config. You can tryhttp://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: You may try with the action filters to allow/disallow the request to that particular controller. So that based on that condition(s) you specify in that action filter the response will be served or denied.

Comment: @saravanan thanks for link, I may use it for testing. but do you mean to write all existing file extensions in routes?

Comment: @Venkat and how to route this action? of course, I meant, that I can create action, that will return File(...). but the question is how to write route

Comment: Yes, hope you don't have too many or just do a inverted condition, which would be easy

Comment: @saravanan it's interesting, but I can have jpg, that should be opened for everybody and some locked jpg. I can write route for closedfolder/file.jpg, but how to write smth for other opened jpgs?

Comment: If that's going to be customer or user specific, you have to use action filters or handle the logic in the on authorization in base controller or writing a wrapper over HTML.action link

Comment: @saravanan yes, it will be user specific. You can post how to use action filters and so on as answer) but I don't understand how can authorization or wrapping links help. Of course I should make links returning 403, but not just hide them, if you meant it

Comment: Are you able to show us all the routes you have setup?

Comment: @MartinBrown I've solved the problem. You can look at comment to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample ActionFilter sample code snippet that you can use

```
public class UriActionFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Sample: somehow identify the user, in case of a custom identity, replace the below line to get the user identifier
            var user = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

            // get the parameter that will let you know what is the image or path that is being requested now
            var ctxParams = filterContext.ActionParameters;

            // if the user does not have the permission to view, return 403
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

In this snippet, you have to replace with the corresponding service calls etc..

W.R.TO the `OnAuthorization`, I was mentioning that you can use so that any one that gets access to the image may hit the URI directly and that can be used filtered. We are using that way to restrict the URI access directly by a given user.

This will help you to override the MVC authorization of each request that the controller gets. This is a more of a restriction by URI alone. However, your case can be satisfied by the above action filter too as parsing of the uri parameters can be quite tricky at times.

Comment: And can you also give example what to write in RouteConfig? Should I enable "RouteExistingFiles"? And how to use filter after that?

Comment: something like this `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*staticfile}", new { staticfile = @".*\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpg|woff|eot|svg|eot|ttf|otf)(/.*)?" });` I use this to skip routing for the static files. you too can form a similar regex to suit your usecase

Comment: thank you, I've reallized it finally! I used this: `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*staticfile}", new { staticfile = @"(\w|\-|\.)*\.(png|ico|css|js|gif|jpg|woff|eot|svg|eot|ttf|otf)(/.*)?" });`, `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*staticfile}", new { staticfile = @"Content/(\w|\-|/|\.)*\.(png|ico|css|js|gif|jpg|woff|eot|svg|eot|ttf|otf)(/.*)?" });` for standart file returning for site/file and for site/Content/.../file. For blocked files I used `routes.Map("Myfolder/{name}", "General", "GetBlockedData");` Really I didn't use action filter, for meanswer of question was just "routes.IgnoreRoute" from your comment :)